# How to deal with Http Session Timeout when using SSO

Tags: java, spring, session, redirect, spring-security-oauth2

I have a **Spring application** ( let's call it **A** for **Authentication**) used as an authentication server. 
**A** is enabling **SSO** for two other applications ( **B for Business and C for Client**).

SSO authentication is done by redirection :

- a User goes to the **B** or **C** URL, he is redirected to the A login page for Authentication. Once logged in, he is redirected back to the **B** or **C** application.

The redirection is done using the **redirectUrl** parameter in the `org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequest`.

So, a user can come either be coming from **B** or **C** application, or logging in directly to his account on the **A** application.

My problem, is the following. Let's take the case of a user wants to connect to the **B** application, once he is redirected to the **A** application , he does not login.
After a while a session timeout occurs, and the session is destroyed, so when he logs in, he is not redirected to the **B** application, but rather to his account on the **A** application.

Possible solutions:

- The obvious way, is to disable timeout on the HttpSession :

  `<session-config>
      <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>`

  This is not a very good idea as it is a security risk, and a threat to overload the authentication server.
- I added a `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`  ApplicationListener in order to detect a timeout and store the request of the session to be destroyed. The main idea was to redirect the user once he is connected after timeout. So on a successful connection, i check my  request cache in the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to see if a request is stored and redirect the user.

  ```
  if (timeOutHandler.isTimeOut()) {
      redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, 
      timeOutHandler.getRequest().getRedirectUrl());
      timeOutHandler.clearSession();
      return;
   }
  ```

  The problem with this approach is that I have no previous knowledge of the user who caused the timeout and I could end up in a scenario like this:

  - A user come from **B** application, causes a timeout.
  - The request with redirect to **B** is stored.
  - Another user comes from **C** application causes also a timeout.
  - The request with redirect to **B** is overridden with the request to 
    redirect  to **C**.
  - The first user tries to connect, he will be redirect to the application **C**

So, what do you think will be the best approach, or do you have a better solution?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it can helps, the solution i went with was to add a hidden field in the login form and store the redirect url, so it can be accessible from the back end even after the session timeout.